# Setting Slicer to yesterday's date

Tags: excel, vba

I need to set a slicer to activate the entry for yesterday's date. I have put together the code below and it deactivates/activates and interacts as I would want it to. The downside is it keeps highlighting fields it shouldn't (see: several days' entries before the appropriate day).

```
Private Sub GroundHogDay()

Dim ydate As Date
ydate = Today - 1
Dim YDateString As String
YDateString = Format$(ydate, "mm/dd/yyyy")

Dim item As SlicerItem

For Each item In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date").SlicerItems
    If item.Name > YDateString Then
        item.Selected = True
    Else
        item.Selected = False
    End If
Next item

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I've tried it with--to no effect.

```
Today - 2
Now - 1
Now - 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually an answer was found:

```
Sub GroundHogDay()
Dim today As Date
today = Now - 2
Dim todayString As String
todayString = Format$(today, "m/d/yyyy")

Dim item As SlicerItem

ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("DATE").ClearManualFilter
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("DATE")
'earliest data available in the data 
.SlicerItems("1/1/2013").Selected = True
.SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
End With

For Each item In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("DATE").SlicerItems

If item.Name = todayString Then
item.Selected = True
Else
item.Selected = False
End If
Next item

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```